# Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service. AWS PinPoint SMS

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services, sms

I have created AWS Pinpoint service for notifications (SMS), Once I implemented the code, I get an exception regarding the IAM Security Credentials. Any Ideas?

I tried one solution of using AWS Explorer in Visual Studio and creating a profile with my account access keys, but I'm not sure what I am supposed to do from there.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: What exception exactly?

Comment: I fixed it. No worries, It had to do with my region parameter that was being stored in AWS Gov.